UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position ???: invalid start byte
I am working with byte strings that include non-ASCII characters, specifically Hebrew text, and I encountered a UnicodeDecodeError when trying to decode the byte string to UTF-8. Here's the problematic code:
t = b'\xd7\x91\xd7\x9c\xd7\xa9\xd7\x95\xd7\xa0\xd7\x99\xd7\xaa:\xa0 '
print(t.decode('utf8'))

The error message I receive is:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 15: invalid start byte

From my understanding, the byte 0xa0 represents a non-breaking space in some encodings, but it seems to cause a problem in UTF-8 decoding. How can I correctly decode this byte string, especially when it contains mixed content like Hebrew characters and potential non-breaking spaces?
Is there a specific method or workaround in Python to handle such scenarios where non-standard or extended ASCII characters (like non-breaking spaces) are embedded within UTF-8 encoded byte strings?

\xA0 is a continuation byte in UTF-8, not a start byte. Seems to me that the : before \xA0 is likely erroneous. Hebrew is the U+0590..U+05FF range of Unicode, so all Hebrew characters should have a start byte of either \xD6 or \xD7 in UTF-8. If the : were replaced with \xD6 then \xD6\xA0 would decode as U+05A0 (◌֠), and if replaced with \xD7 then \xD7\xA0 would decode as U+05E0 (נ).

Shalom!
I believe the \xa0 is the mistake. The : does make sense in the context of "בלשונית" which is "in the tab" in Hebrew.

The issue you encountered with the UnicodeDecodeError arises because the byte 0xa0 is not recognized as a valid UTF-8 sequence on its own. This byte often represents a non-breaking space in encodings such as ISO-8859-1 or Windows-1252 but is not valid in UTF-8 without proper preceding bytes.
When you use errors="ignore" in your decode method:
print(t.decode('utf8', errors="ignore"))

This tells Python to ignore parts of the byte string that it cannot decode properly. In the case of your string, Python skips over the 0xa0 byte because it cannot be decoded to UTF-8, and proceeds to decode the rest of the bytes, which are valid UTF-8 representations of Hebrew characters.
The output:

בלשונית:

Another option is errors='replace', which will replace undecodable bytes with the official Unicode replacement character � (U+FFFD):
